# No output from bash -c over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

How come when I run this on my local machine I get output

```
$ bash -c 'a=$(date) && echo $a'
Thu Feb 20 23:12:26 MST 2014
```

but if I try it over ssh (I have a public key on the other box, but no forced commands in authorized_keys)

```
$ ssh nathan@gnunix bash -c 'a=$(date) && echo $a'
```

Just a blank line is printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `bash -c` probably, just this would be able to print date:

```
ssh nathan@gnunix 'a=$(date) && echo $a'
```

If you must use `bash -c` then escape `$` like this (otherwise `$` is interpreted by current shell not remote one)

```
ssh nathan@gnunix "bash -c 'a=\$(date) && echo \$a'"
Fri Feb 21 01:22:42 EST 2014
```

Comment: Any idea why they are using [a `bash -c` approach](http://quickshiftin.com/blog/2013/11/performance-boost-fabric-scripts/) in [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/)?

Comment: Thank you, the second example is helpful.